# How to open a program and make it run on the currently open console app in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I was wondering if there is any possible way to make a console application open in the parent console. Like how MS-DOS opens the app when you type something like `<path_to_file>\<filename>.exe`, it doesn't close the CMD window, it just opens the app you typed the name for in the current window.

I need to do this in C++, without using system(), as everyone knows about the security risks etc.

I tried `CreateProcess()` but that opened another window. I am not worried about portability, this is a Windows only application anyways.

Comment: The *default* behaviour is for a console application to inherit the parent's console window.  If that isn't what you're seeing, you'll need to provide more details in order for us to work out why not.  Start by showing the code that calls CreateProcess, and by double-checking that both the parent and child are in fact console applications.  (My best guess: the parent application is *not* a console application, but you're *starting* it from a command-line console.)

Comment: After reading through the post above, I realized my mistake. It was simply that I was using the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag. Thank you.